# Is it possible to get an array of objects with query that returns only one object?

Tags: graphql

For example github graphql has repository query

```
type Query {
  repository(name: string): Repository
}
```

And I have array of names `["foo1", "foo2", ...]`

How can I get array `[Repository]` in one request?

Answer (score 0):

Is possible only if you change the functionality of that query.
Just implement a new query `repositories` with parameter `names` which returns `[Repository]`

Comment: But I cannot do that, because it's the github api.

Comment: I though that is just an example. Well in this case you can start a topic https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/bd-p/api or not recommended but still a solution 'use the same query for each name in the array'